# How can I apply shipping rules to multiple states in Expresso Store?

Tags: expresso-store, expresso, shipping

I’m currently setting up shipping methods within an Expresso Store site. Shipping costs are based on total product costs (not weight). The breakdown is shown below:

Standard
Up to $50  $4.95
$50-$100 is $7.95
$101-$250 is $8.95
$251-$500 is $9.95
$501-$1500 is $19.95
$1501-$2500 is $39.95

2nd Day
Up to $100 is $12.95
$101-$250 is $15.95
$251-$500 is $17.95
$501-$1500 is $29.95
$1501-$2500 is $59.95

Next Day
Up to $100 is $34.95
$101-$250 is $39.95
$251-$500 is $44.95
$501-$1500 is $49.95
$1501-$2500 is $79.95

I’ve entered all these with no problem – they apply to all US states – but, shipping to western states must be $1.00 more for all of the above. There are 24 states that qualify as western. Since it doesn't seem possible to select multiple states from the dropdown in Filters, it means I’d have to enter each variation state by state. The would be 16 filters x 24 western states. Is there a way to do this without manually entering all 384 variations for the western states?

Answer (score 0):

The only way to get around that without all the manual labour is to write a custom extension to handle it. That way you can specify the states to add the extra dollar to and it will apply it automatically. You can even use our Adjustments handling if you wanted to and then you'd be able to itemise the extra cost if you wanted/needed to using our [{adjustments} tags](https://exp-resso.com/docs/checkout_tag.html#adjustments_loop).